# Access to fetch at **link** from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: django, redirect, cors, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to exchange the authorization code for an access token for a Google Calendar integration. I was following [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python_4). The examples shown there were for Flask, but I'm using Django. The problem is, I can't redirect to `authorization_url` because it says

**Access to fetch at *link* from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

```
 @api_view(['GET'])
    def authorize(request):
        flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
            CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
            scopes=SCOPES)
        flow.redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:3000/'
        authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
            access_type='offline',
            include_granted_scopes='true')
        response = redirect(authorization_url)
        return response
```

However in my settings.py I have:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
"http://localhost:3000",
"http://127.0.0.1:3000",]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: have you tried removing the `/` from the end, so that url matches the one in the allowed list?

Comment: @2293980990 yeah I tried that, didn't help

Comment: can you please post your middleware settings

Comment: I've never used this API myself, but reading the docs. Have you checked that you follow Google's setup prerequisites and that the valid redirect URI on their servers match yours? Can you try setting `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True` and see if that helps?

Comment: @2293980990 I set `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True` and it didn't work for me. And yes, I have checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this package: https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

So you can try to add the origin to "Trusted Origins" in Django settings:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['www.something.com']
```

or like that, for all origins (do not recommend):

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

Comment: CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS and CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True just don't work for me